# Target an element with a data attribute and dynamically set the value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set the span element with a value but I get the error span is not defined when I target the span with a data attribute(data-job-value) using a `querySelector()`

```js
let properties = ['name', 'age'];

properties.forEach(property => {
  let spanElement = document.querySelector(`.prop[data-${property}]`);
  spanElement.textContent = property;
});
```

```html
<span class="prop" data-name></span>
```

Comment: what do you think about some more code? Like the html side...

Comment: I just added the html. I'm trying to target a span with a specific data attribute. When I get that, then I update the UI with the property

Comment: Do you mean the length of the array does not much with the number of span elements in the UI?

Comment: Your code works, you get null in the snippet because you do not have an element with the `data-age` attribute

Comment: Everyday is a school day, I had no knowledge of [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Thanks for introducing me to the concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's beacause you don't have a element matching ".prop[data-age]" and thus `querySelector` returns `null`

```js
let properties = ['name', 'age'];

properties.forEach(property => {
  let spanElement = document.querySelector(`.prop[data-${property}]`);

  if (spanElement === null) {
    console.log(`Error: no matching elements found for query ".prop[data-${property}]"`);
    return;
  }

  spanElement.textContent = property;
});
```

```html
<span class="prop" data-name></span>
```

There will be no error if you have the matching element like following

```js
let properties = ['name', 'age'];

properties.forEach(property => {
  let spanElement = document.querySelector(`.prop[data-${property}]`);

  if (spanElement === null) {
    console.log(`Error: no matching elements found for query ".prop[data-${property}]"`);
    return;
  }

  spanElement.textContent = property;
});
```

```html
<span class="prop" data-name></span>
<span class="prop" data-age></span>
```

Comment: @shutsuke You're welcome! You should consider accepting the answer since it worked for you